# Why is it not recognising this type in the extension?

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I'm trying to add a widget to my app, with a button which triggers a function in one of the view controller, but I don't want it to open the app.

So far I've written this :

```
@IBAction func startTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let activityVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "") as! ActivityViewController
    activityVC.updateUI()
}
```

But, the above code gives me the following error

> "Use of undeclared type 'ActivityViewController'"

I've defined Activity View controller in my main project, how should I use it here?

Comment: Is the ActivityViewController  in the app extension  or the main app?

Comment: In the main app

Answer (score 0):

Add `ActivityViewController` class to your project. In `Main.storyboard` add viewcontroller with `ActivityViewController` class & give Identifier ("ActivityViewController") to this ViewController. Get your ViewController as below.

```
@IBAction func startTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let activityVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ActivityViewController") as! ActivityViewController
    activityVC.updateUI()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding ActivityViewController in your widget target.

Select the view controller file in Xcode -> Click View in menu bar -> Inspectors ->  Show file inspector

On the right side in your file inspector you Will have Target Membership menu where you can tick your widget target's checkbox to include your ActivityViewController in your widget and your main project.